# How can I avoid typing the "source ~/.bash_profile" command in the terminal every time?

Tags: macos, terminal, anaconda

I just installed Anaconda. When I try to run a command, lets say `conda --version`, I get the following error message:

```
zsh: command not found: conda
```

When I type in:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Everything works:

```
conda --version

conda 4.8.0
```

But I have to type the command every time I start the terminal.

My .bash_profile looks like this:

```
# added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

What can I do to fix this?

System: macOS

Answer (score 1):

place `source ~/.bash_profile` into `~/.zsh`

Bash loads .bash_profile during init, for zsh it’s .zsh

Default shell was changed from bash to zsh with macOS Catalina, so that’s why there is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The .zsh file did not exist. So I created it with textedit and saved it in my user folder. In the file I included the command. However it is not working. If I try open .zsh it still says that it does not exist. But I can see it here in my files. The open command works with every other file, for instance .bash_profile...

Comment: You have to restart the terminal. Make sure the .zsh file is in the same directory like .bash_profile.

Comment: Ok. I used the vi command to write the file. My .zsh looks like this:


source ~/.bash_profile


That is not working however. It is in the same folder as my .bash_profile